# count list by order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to count a given list like:

```
list = [1 , 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3]
```

and the result will be:

```
2122141223
```

So what the code does is count by order how many times the x number is in row. In the example above there is 1 and then another 1, so = 2 (the number of occurence) 1 (the number itself)

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6]
i = 0
n = len(list)
c = 1
list2 =[]
while i in range(0, n) and c in range (1 , n):
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        listc= i+c
        listx = str(listc)
        list2.insert(i, i+c)
        i += 1
        c += 1
    else:
        f = i + 1
        i += 1
        c += 1
```

That's what I've done and I don't know how to continue.

What I'm trying to do is a loop that checks if the number are identical, if they are they will continue to the next number until it runs with different number.

Comment: Please, show, what have you already tried and what does not work

Comment: so far i've manage to do  a loop that just copy the other list... im stuck basically

Comment: @mars edit that into your question, it's unreadable without formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3]
print ''.join('{}{}'.format(len(list(g)), k) for k,g in groupby(my_list))
```

Giving you the following output:

```
2122141223
```

The `k` gives you the key (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 2, 3), and the `g` gives an iterator. By converting this to a list, its length can be determined.

Or without using the `groupby` function, you could do the following:

```
my_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3]

current = my_list[0]
count = 1
output = []

for value in my_list[1:]:
    if value == current:
        count += 1
    else:
        output.append('{}{}'.format(count, current))
        current = value
        count = 1

output.append('{}{}'.format(count, current))
print ''.join(output)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but since we have not used "imports" yet i dont think i can use it for now, is there another way?